# Custom knockout component

Tags: templates, knockout.js, components

Is it possible to use conditional logic inside of a custom knockout component? The goal is to render different templates based on a specific parameter provided to the knockout component.

Take a really simple example :

```
ko.components.register('network', {
    viewModel : function(params) {
        var someParam = params.someDeterminer;
    },
    template : render different template entirely (maybe loaded from external file) based on the value of someParam
}
```

Is this possible?

Update :

The solution I accepted *almost* works. What I found is that knockout looks for the first declaration of the template. After that, you cannot update the template. A slight edit to his code and it works. Something like this :

```
ko.components.register('network', {
    viewModel : function(params) {
        var self = this;
        var someParam = params.someDeterminer;


        if(someParam=="somecondition")
            this.templateToLoad("someTemplate")
        else 
            this.templateToLoad("someOtherTemplateToLoad")

    },
template : '<div data-bind="template:{name: templateToLoad}"></div>'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
ko.components.register('network', {
    viewModel : function(params) {
        var self = this;
        var someParam = params.someDeterminer;
        self.templateToLoad = ko.observable();

        if(someParam=="somecondition")
            self.templateToLoad("someTemplate")
        else self.templateToLoad("someOtherTemplateToLoad")

    },
    template : '<div data-bind="template:{name: templateToLoad}"></div>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a component that branches to different components. It would forward the view model down into the correct component.

```
<!-- ko if: someParam === 'templateA' -->
    <componentA params="viewModel: $component"></componentA>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: someParam === 'templateB' -->
    <componentB params="viewModel: $component"></componentB>
<!-- /ko -->
```